# Нужна помощь с Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, html, веб-программирование, asp.net, asp.net-core

`<a asp-action="Create" class="c">Добавить модель</a>`

Есть такая ссылка, при нажатии на которую - пользователь попадает на страницу `Create.cshtml`, где находится форма для добавления нового элемента.

А как сделать эту ссылку кнопкой?
Как можно `asp-action="Create"` использовать в теге `<button>`?

Comment: Как вариант использовать bootstrap-класс `btn`.

Comment: Спасибо. Что то я сам не додумался. А вообще возможно использовать asp-action в теге button? Интерес возник просто.

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```
<form asp-action="Create">
    <button type="submit">Добавить модель</button>
</form>
```

Но лучше все же с помощью стилей сделать ссылку похожей на кнопку.

Comment: Чем лучше? Если у элемента семантика кнопки - он должен быть кнопкой.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Что же такое в вашем понимании "семантика кнопки"? По-вашему элемент, который переводит пользователя на другую страницу, имеет семантику кнопки, а не ссылки?

Comment: Формы должны использовать post.

Comment: Если вы считаете, что мой ответ не отвечает на поставленный вопрос "как сделать ссылку кнопкой", то можете прокомментировать это. Высказывание своих субъективных мнений по поводу вещей, не касающихся этого вопроса или ответа на этот вопрос, не несет в себе никакой пользы.

Comment: @Groxan элемент который выполняет при нажатии некоторое действие - да, имеет семантику кнопки

Answer (score 1):

```css
a {
  padding: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid ligntblue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid darkblue;
  border-left: 1px solid ligntblue;
  border-right: 1px solid darkblue;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  cursor: default;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: black;
}

a:active:hover {
  border-top: 1px solid darkblue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightblue;
  border-left: 1px solid darkblue;
  border-right: 1px solid lightblue;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">This is an anchor tag</a>
```

```html
<a href="#"><button type="button">This is an anchor tag</button></a>
```

Comment: А можно ли сделать это тегом button? То есть asp-action="Create" выполнить в теге button, возможно такое?